# Azure - Availability Zones - encryption

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-availability-zones

I have Azure VM's which use encryption. Is it possible to make use of Availability Zones to be Datacenter resilient. Where do i need to store my Enterprise vault server keys, what about ipsec and bitlocker encryption.

If this isn't supported yet by MS just let me know, I will look to other solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Availabilty Zones are still in preview so you would need to sign up to be part of it

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/availability-zones/az-overview

But to answer your question, Azure Encryption should have no issue with using Availability Zones. It is essentially the same thing as an Availability set just across data centers. So storing your Vault Keys would be no different if you were using any kind of availability set or not.